# How to print the binary representation of a float in Go?

Tags: go, types, format

The fmt package allows us to print a binary representation of integers with %b. How to get an equivalent result for floats instead of the scientific notation?

```
fmt.Printf("%b", 52) // 110100
fmt.Printf("%b", 52.0) // 7318349394477056p-47
```

Comment: Fractional binary like `110100.0` or the actual floating-point bits?

Comment: @Ry I was looking for the floating-point representation, but it could be a good idea to show how to get the fractional binary too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the raw bits of a float with the `math` package using [`math.Float64bits`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float64bits) or [`math.Float32bits`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float32bits). Combining this with the `%b` formatting verb will display the binary representation of the float.

```
fmt.Printf("%b\n", math.Float64bits(52.0))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/oJKMqhsLdOA

Comment: Thank you! And for those who also need to get a float from the representation, the math package provides us with `math.Float32frombits` and `math.Float64frombits`.